# How can Algolia be configured to treat an ampersand as literal character?

Tags: algolia

By default, Algolia doesn't recognize ampersands as characters. For example: "K&N", "AT&T", or "PG&E" will match in search but the ampersand is not bolded (false negative), and results include those without ampersands (false positives).

You can see this behavior here: https://demo.algolia.com/instant-search-demo/?q=at%26t

Answer (score 8):

Algolia web dashboard -> `Indices` -> `Ranking` -> `Optional Words & Separators` -> `Separator characters to index`:

Add the ampersand (`&`) to this field and hit `Save`.

Comment: Could also be a good idea to then define `&` <> `and` as a synonym.

Comment: The settings name is `separatorsToIndex` - https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/separatorsToIndex/